# Progmatically configuring Spring Security OAUTH

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, oauth, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Prefer to progmatically configure spring security oauth for sake of consistency. The documentation covers xml but doesn't seem to mention progmatic configuration.

Whats the Java equivalent of the xml (extract from the sample project) configuration?

```
<oauth:consumer resource-details-service-ref="resourceDetails" oauth-failure-page="/oauth_error.jsp">
    <oauth:url pattern="/google/**" resources="google"/>
    <oauth:url pattern="/login/**" resources="none"/>
  </oauth:consumer>

  <oauth:resource-details-service id="resourceDetails">
    <oauth:resource id="google" key="anonymous" secret="anonymous"
                    request-token-url="https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken"
                    user-authorization-url="https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken"
                    access-token-url="https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken"
                    request-token-method="GET"
                    access-token-method="GET">
      <oauth:addtionalParameter name="scope" value="https://picasaweb.google.com/data/"/>
      <oauth:addtionalParameter name="xoauth_displayname" value="Tonr Example Application"/>
    </oauth:resource>
  </oauth:resource-details-service>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Java DSL for configuring OAuth1.0a. You can create bean definitions manually, or use the XML. Note that for Google APIs you can use OAuth2 (which does have a Java DSL). If anyone is interested in contributing a Java DSL there is already a pull request with a big refactoring of the OAuth1.0a pieces, so it might be good to start from there.